# Data structures for quantum computers

Tags: data-structures, quantum-computing

In classical computers we have List,Queue,Tree & etc data structures, since classical computers using 1's & 0's on those data structures. Then what happens when it comes to quantum computers,
Do they(computer scientists) need to create new data structures ?
Or use existing data structures with some sort of optimization ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.0833

Comment: @DmitriUrbanowicz, yeah i read it. but it says something about use of existing data structures with qubits. Yet those data structures are designed for work with bits, right ?

Comment: Qubits are also binary, just like classical bits. Nothing prevents you from using classical data structures. Quantum amplitudes are more like probabilities rather than a value you can use as an input.

Comment: Though it seems to be an interesting question, if there are interesting data structures that rely on effects of QC.

Comment: @DmitriUrbanowicz "Qubits are also binary, just like classical bits" how so ?. correct me if i wrong, bits has only 1 and 0, but in qubits which is superposition of particle has 1 and 0 and both at the same time.

Comment: A qubit can only be in one of the two mutually exclusive states. There can be uncertainty about the whole state of the system, which is described by superposition. This is like having randomness in a classical computer. What’s unusual, though, is that the qubits are put in such conditions, that it becomes possible to get destructive interference of different possibilities.

Comment: Mathematically, what I say is just the linearity of QM. If you don’t use non-classical gates (like Hadamard) in your curcuit, then you just get classical computation for each of the components of the superposition.

Comment: @DmitriUrbanowicz thanks for the clarification.